# How can I do a total row in a query Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have this currently formula:

SE(E(B1="Leads";C1="Crescente";D1="Top5";E1="Tudo");{QUERY(Dados!G2:N;"Select Col5,Sum(Col6),(Sum(Col8)/Sum(Col6)),Sum(Col8) Group By Col5 Order By Sum(Col6) ASC Limit 5 Label (Sum(Col8)/Sum(Col6)) 'CPL', Sum(Col6) 'Leads', Sum(Col8) 'Valor Investido'";1);
{"TOTAL"\QUERY(Dados!G2:N;"Select Sum(Col6), (Sum(Col8)/Sum(Col6)), Sum(Col8) Order By Sum(Col6) DESC Limit 5 Label (Sum(Col8)/Sum(Col6)) '', Sum(Col6)'', Sum(Col8)''";1)}}

When I top5 (limit 5) my total still showing the total column. Any suggestions?
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xRZEy3uO2AUnHgrrMexqcQuAI-Z02qmtYV9iNkemmSM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Here's one general approach you may try:*

```js
IF(AND(B1="Leads";C1="Crescente";D1="Top5";E1="Tudo");let(Σ;QUERY(Dados!G2:N;"Select Col5,Sum(Col6),(Sum(Col8)/Sum(Col6)),Sum(Col8) Group By Col5 Order By Sum(Col6) ASC Limit 5 Label (Sum(Col8)/Sum(Col6)) 'CPL', Sum(Col6) 'Leads', Sum(Col8) 'Valor Investido'";1);
    vstack(Σ;hstack("TOTAL";bycol(choosecols(Σ;2;3;4);lambda(Λ;sum(Λ))))))
```

`logic`: *this part simply stacks the query results on TOP and the sums the columns 2,3,4 to be placed below*

```js
vstack(Σ;hstack("TOTAL";bycol(choosecols(Σ;2;3;4);lambda(Λ;sum(Λ)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Owwww! Have never ever seen anything like that. Thank you so much! –